# Add Where clause at Runtime to SQL

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and have some trouble.

I have a report which is deployed and I can show this report
in a project using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.
That's fine, but now I have to make up some code for changing the
Query used in my datasets:
I need to get my sql, and modify it ( put on some "Where... ", "exists",
and so on ) - then put the sql back in the report and then execute/show the
report.

I am familiar with parameters, but parameters can't cover my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The expression used for the SQL statement for your dataset is simply that - an expression. It can be anything you want it to be, including a string that you build. For example, you could have a parameter that indicated how to build the SQL:

```
="SELECT ThisField, ThatField "
& "FROM MyTable "
& IIF(Parameters!AddExistsClause.Value, "WHERE SomeId IN (SELECT Id FROM OtherTable) ", "")
```

You can even add a reference to your own DLL that builds the SQL:

```
="SELECT " & MyDLL.ReportFunctions.GetFields(Parameters!FieldName.Value)
& "FROM " & Parameters!Database.Value & ".dbo." & Parameters!Database.TableName "
& MyDLL.ReportFunctions.TableJoins(Parameters!FieldName.Value)
& MyDLL.ReportFunctions.WhereClause(Parameters!FieldName.Value)
```

Comment: Can that be the same case for Shared Dataset on the Server